# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'book' available as request attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

Стартовая страница.
В настройках tomcat **http://localhost:8080/index**

При компиляции возникает ошибка такого рода

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'book' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
```

**BookController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes({"book", "selectedBook", "isUpdating", "bookList"})
public class BookController {

@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Autowired
private Serviceable<Book> bookService;


@ModelAttribute("book")
public Book getBook(){
    return new Book();
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/index", "/books", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupForm(ModelMap model){
    Book book = new Book();
    //ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView("books", "book", book);
    //ModelMap model = mv.getModelMap();
    //Map<String, Object> map = mv.getModel();
    //map.put("selectedBook", new 
    //map.put("book", new Book());
    //map.put("bookList", bookService.getAll());
    //map.put("isUpdating", false);
    model.addAttribute("book", book);
    model.addAttribute("bookList", bookService.getAll());
    model.addAttribute("selectedBook", new Book());
    model.addAttribute("isUpdating", false);
    return "books";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/book.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doActions(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book,
                        @ModelAttribute("selectedBook") Book selectedBook,
                        BindingResult result,
                        @RequestParam String action,
                        Map<String, Object> map, ModelMap model){
/*some code*/
```

**books.jsp**

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/pages/includes.jsp"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bookshelf</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Books Data</h1>
<div class="edit_form">
<form:form action="book.do" method="POST" modelAttribute="book">
....
```

**структура проекта**

[image: структура_проекта]

P.S.: файлов диспатчера нет - все делаю через JavaConfig

что я уже пробовал:

1. Делать через Model
2. делать через ModelMap
3. делать через ModelAndView
4. загружать в @SessionAtttibutes
5. пересобирал проект (Maven: clean - compile|install)
6. создавал новый/перезапускал сервер
7. привязывал @ModelAttrubute("book")

Средства сборки и компиляции

1. Maven
2. IntellijIdea UltimateVersion
3. Tomcat 8.5.23
4. Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE
5. Hibernate 5.2.10.Final
6. MySQL 5.1.34

Comment: Перейди на спринг бут и не парься

Comment: я бы с радостью, но ТЗ запрещает пока что это)

Answer (score 1):

предположительно: ошибка была в том, что я не за маппил свой контроллер, на что ругался DispatcherServlet

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.javarush")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
/*config options*/
```